# Adding similar Web Services to .NET C# application

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I'm new in web services and I'm developing a C# WCF service that is calling an external service from another company to get some client data (for example: name, address, phone, etc), this part is working fine so far.

The external service is based on a standard XML Schema, and other companies will have soon the same service generated from the same XML Schema, using the same name methods and returning the same type of xml file.

My first question is that after I complete this first implementation, there is any way to add “dynamically” the other external companies services, having the information of their URL/Ports/etc, or do I have to insert each on them manually as services reference in my internal service project every time I need to add a new one, then compile and re-deploy?

My second question is related with the data contract /members, my understanding is that even if they are returning the same XML files, their data contracts/members will be different, is that true? So I’ll have to make a specific code to read the information I need from their data contracts for each new external company?? If this is true I have been thinking to make a generic code to read the raw xml, is this the best choice?

Answer (score 1):

While C# is a compiled language it does support pluggin architecture through MEF. You could use this and add a small plugin .dll for each of your sources.

That being said it's quite possible that all you need is a configuration list containing connection details for each of your sources and connecting to them dynamically. That will only work if they're using the exact same schema, so that the objects they serve will serialize the same for all sources. You will have to instantiate the proxy dynamically through code using that configuration then, of course.

I should add something for your second question. As long as you're the one defining the contract, it doesn't matter if their actual objects are different. All you care about on your end is the xml they serve, and that you can connect using your representation. In fact, you can generate the contract as a .wsdl document. Each of the service-implementer can then generate domain objects from that. On the other hand if you're not the one "owning" the contract, some of the sources may decide to do it slightly differently, which will cause you a headache. Hopefully that's not your scenario though.

Best of luck! :)

Comment: @user1558528 You're most welcome. Added some bonus information for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is that after I complete this first implementation, there is any way to add “dynamically” the other external companies services, having the information of their URL/Ports/etc

Unfortunately yes, you will have add service, compile it and deploy every time

> My second question is related with the data contract /members, my understanding is that even if they are returning the same XML files, their data contracts/members will be different, is that true?

If you will use auto generated every service will create different contracts. I would think about creating you own class and convert external classes using reflection and extension methods